# How to use models associated with a user in Django when rendering an HTML page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm in the learning stages of django. I just dived into a project to learn the framework and am having a series of questions throughout the process.

I basically want to have individual pages for users who create a task list and have them post tasks to their own page.

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```
# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank = True)
    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class TaskItem(models.Model):
    taskn = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    usern = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In my template, if the user has their task entered, how do I call it to render onto the page?

## My View:

```
def profile_page(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    taskitems = user.taskn_set.all()
    return render_to_response('profile.html', {}, context)
```

Current issue:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'taskn_set'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ request.user.taskitem_set.all }}` would give you all the related task items. Now, to display it in your template:

```
{% for task_item in user.taskitem_set.all %}
    {{ task_item.task_n }}
{% endfor %}
```

would display the list of tasks.

Here is the documentation on [reverse-queries on foreign key (related_name)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) Also, [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name)

Comment: Yes,, updating the qeustion with relevant links, so you can understand better.

Comment: I've updated my issue, but am getting a set attribute error, any ideas?

Comment: can you edit your question with the stack trace, and notify me here ?

Comment: It is not `taskn_set` , it is `taskitem_set` - read the answer carefully, as it could be a little confusing.

Comment: Ah, ok. It now returns 'User' object has no attribute 'TaskItem_set'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77987/discussion-between-ryan-and-karthikr).

Comment: @karthikr sorry for my comment ;-) I didn't knew that this was community reviewed !

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like this:

```
{% for task in user.taskitem_set.all %}
    {{ task.task_n }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will fetch all TaskItem instances related to your user. (notice the **extra database query**)

While i don't know how your view works, i will assume that you are making the right checks to make sure that every user can only see his own tasks.

One **performance trick** you will find most useful is to use prefetch_related('taskitem_set'), this will prefetch the TaskItem instances as long as your UserProfile instance with one query:

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=user_id).prefetch_related('taskitem_set')
```

You can tune the code to match your preferences.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here, you are prefetching on an entire queryset - not exactly what is needed in this scenario. ALso, The `TaskItem` is associated with a `User` and not `UserProfile`, so this query is not accurate.

Comment: oh thanks for pointing that out, i actually wrote this on two different time stamps lol